# Solid of revolution using washer method(Gives negative answer)

Tags: area, solid-of-revolution

My teacher even knew that the answer should not be negative but it turned out to be negative. The given was y=x^2, y=4x-x^2, revolving about the y-axis. Here are some of the solution presented, I hope someone could help me find where I went wrong while solving. Thanks in advance. My teacher can’t even find the error that I have committed.

Edit: As I did the right - left thingy, the answer was -112/3(pi) cu. units.

V=(pi)[(sqrt(y))^2-(sqrt(4-y)+2)^2)]dy

V=(pi)[2y-4sqrt(4-y)-8]dy

V=(pi)[y^2+8/3(4-y)^3/2-8y] limit from 0 to 4 <——already integrated

Applying the limits

V=(pi)[16+8/3(0-8)]

V=-112/3(pi) cu. units. Is there anything done wrong? I hope someone can spot what is wrong. I really need the correct answer utgently. Thanks for those who can help.

Comment: Are you sure you've included your work in the post? I'm not seeing it

Comment: Sorry if you’ve not seen it. Never knew that my photo was not uploaded. Now you could probably check again. Sorry for the incovenience. The graph is the same as what the decaf-math answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: if you plan on using the $y$-axis as your axis of rotation for the washer method, then you are going to need to integrate with respect to $y$, and you need to solve each of the equations in terms of $x$: $$y = x^2 \implies \pm\sqrt y = x \implies \sqrt y = x \checkmark \qquad\text{(Since we need the right-half)}$$
However, the other equation is not so straightforward. You will need to complete the square to help eliminate one of the $x$'s: $$\begin{align}y &= 4x-x^2\\ &= -(x^2-4x + 4 - 4) \\ &= -(x-2)^2 + 4 \\ \implies y- 4 &= -(x-2)^2\\ \pm\sqrt{4-y} &= x-2 \\ \implies \pm\sqrt{4-y}+2 &= x\\ \implies -\sqrt{4-y}+2 &= x. \qquad\text{(Since we need the left-half)}\end{align}$$

[image]

Notice how $\sqrt y = x$ is the rightmost graph and $-\sqrt{4-y}+2 = x$ is the leftmost. You will need to do **right - left** in your radius function when computing the integral.

Comment: Yea. I got the same constraints. Got same solutions but my answer turns out negative. Go check my post again and look if I did something wrong. Ps: I edited the post.

Comment: @Bido262, one thing that I notice immediately is that you use the wrong half of one of the functions. You wrote $$V=\pi\int_0^4[(\sqrt y )^2-(\sqrt{4-y}+2)^2)]dy,$$ but it should be $$V=\pi\int_0^4\left[(\sqrt y)^2 - (2-\sqrt{4-y})^2\right]dy.$$ If you compute that instead, you get a positive answer.

Comment: Omg. Finally. Thanks mate, will be presenting this damn problem tomorrow. The answer turned out to be 16/3(pi) cu. units. Pls correct me if am wrong.

Comment: @Bido262 $\displaystyle {16\pi\over3}$ is indeed the answer I received.

Comment: How to mark this question as anwered?

Comment: There's a checkmark right below the upvote/downvote on the left of the question. You click the checkmark to indicate the question has been answered. You can also upvote if you haven't already. :)